# Hiding the add to cart button for woocommerce regarding variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a website in WordPress using Woocommerce and I've managed to hide the 'add to cart button' of the products for guest users and users according to a specific role. The php script I found (actually it was here in stackoverflow) works really well and hides the add to cart button in all simple products but not on the variable products according to the specific role.

This was the code I used for the role of Reseller

```
/* REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON FOR RESELLER USERS */
add_action('wp_loaded','get_user_role');
function get_user_role(){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if(count($current_user->roles)!==0){
if($current_user->roles[0]=='Reseller'){
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
}
}
}
```

It works fine with simple products but doesn't work with variable products. Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable` hooks

```
add_action('wp_loaded','get_user_role');
function get_user_role(){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(count($current_user->roles)!==0){
        if($current_user->roles[0]=='Reseller'){
            add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
            add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', '__return_false');
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can do like this.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'hide_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2);
function hide_add_to_cart_button($purchasable, $variation) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(count($current_user->roles)!==0){
        if($current_user->roles[0]=='Reseller'){
            $purchasable = false;
        }
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
```

**UPDATE as per OP comment**

You can use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook and remove the `woocommerce_single_variation` hook.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_add_to_cart_button', 1);
function hide_add_to_cart_button() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(count($current_user->roles)!==0){
        if($current_user->roles[0]=='Reseller'){
            remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bhautik. Thank you so much for your reply. It does remove the add to cart function, meaning it doesn't work, but it still shows. Is there any way of hiding it?